# No implicit rule found in makefile

Tags: c, makefile

My makefile execution fails each time due to a dependency. I don't want to overshare so I will try to only share the necessary info. I am using GNUWin32 make so that my windows box can execute it (a constraint I have to deal with) and I am able to compile/make a decent number of files in the src\\Framework\...\\%.o realm from ..\\src\\Framework\...\\%.c.

It seems that as long as it is at least 2 folders deep, the Makefile works. Ex: src\\test.o doesn't compile but src\\tester\\test.o will compile.

My error is as follows:

> make: *** No rule to make target 'src\\control.o', needed by 'proj.elf'.  Stop.

but I also have the following rule which is executed from a dependency of target all:

> src\\%.o: ..\\src\\%.c

which should make src\\control.o as long as ..\\src\\%.c exists.

---

When I use `make -d all` I notice that it ends with

> No implicit rule found for 'src\\control.o'.
>
> Finished prerequisites of target file 'src\\control.o'.
>
> Must remake target 'src\\control.o'

If anyone has a solution to make this work I would be glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently, even GNUWin32 make uses Unix style filenames for the targets and dependencies but in order to use the mkdir command, you must use Windows style filenames.

> test/windows/%.o: ../test/windows/%.c
>
> mkdir test\windows\make_this_dir\

I hope this helps anyone with a similar issue.